# Reverse a sentence word by word

Tags: code-golf, string, array, whitespace

## The setting

"Well I actually wrote the sql library they, the maintainers actually.."

"Right, but do you have any experience working with django?"

" ...no I don't use frameworks"

After the phone interview is over, you feel like you really need a coffee. While the brew is heating, you check your messages on BusinessBook.

Yet another recruiter appears interested in your profile and would like to have an interview for a remote position, they sent an easy challenge as a prescreening question. To be honest, you aren't sure whether it's a legitimate inquiry or whether they are mass messaging half the globe.

Your mind wanders at the challenge, it's mockingly simple, but you wonder of the thousands ways there are to solve them, the lax wording and lack of constraints leave open endless possibilities. You mustn't spend much time dwelling on this though, otherwise you are left wide open for spam  or Denial of Service attacks. There's lots of other things to do.

The water starts to boil, take too long and your coffee will burn, you are about to delete the message, but you figure you could answer with just one line of code:

## The constraints

- Write the program that solves the following challenge.
- You will be sending the answer through a chat system, so make sure that no whitespace issues arise.
- Use the least amount of characters possible. For every character that you write, some of those coffee cells are irreversibly burnt.

## The challenge

"So before we set up an interview, could you please solve this short technical test?

Write a program to reverse the word in a given sentence. For example,

input: today is the first day of the rest of my life

output: life my of rest the of day first the is today

Thanks!"

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Unfortunately, this question was asked before. For future challenges: 1) It is recommended to use [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) to get some feedback (including dupe detection) before posting to main, 2) Please avoid [excessively long back stories](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13632/58563) (incidentally, that's an issue that can also be found in the original challenge, to a lesser extent), 3) Make sure to include the winning criterion (here: code-golf) as a tag.